# Regex in Symfony 6

Tags: regex, symfony

The following regex doesn't work in Symfony Sonata form:

```
$form->add('licensePlate', TextType::class, [
   'constraints' => new Assert\Regex([
       'pattern' => '/[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{2}/',
       'match' => false,
       'message' => 'The license plate must be in the format AA-123-BB',
   ])
]);
```

whereas in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) it does.

I wonder if I have to add something else for Symfony.

Comment: Why is `'match' => false`?

Comment: Set `'match' => true` (or omit it), currently that is saying *don't* match (or do the opposite of) that pattern. [Docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#match)

Comment: I'd suggest adding [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) as well, as this can do a partial match (`AAA-123-BCDE` would be a false positive). So the full regex should be `/^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{2}$/i` (the `i` being a case-insensitive match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Change [*`match`*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#match) value from `false` to `true`
- Use `^` and `\z` anchors to the regex pattern so as to match the whole string with this pattern.

So you can use

```php
$form->add('licensePlate', TextType::class, [
   'constraints' => new Assert\Regex([
       'pattern' => '/^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{2}\z/',
       'match' => true,
       'message' => 'The license plate must be in the format AA-123-BB',
   ])
]);
```